# Why $e = \exp\left\{ -\int_0^1 \log y dy\right\}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Given positive real numbers $a_k, k=1,2,...,$ let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ where we take $f(x)$ to be equal to $a_k$ on the interval $(k-1, k]$ for $1\le k < \infty$. If $f(ny)$ is replaced by $y$ in 
$$\exp\left\{ \int_0^1 \log f(ny) dy\right\},$$
then 
$$e = \exp\left\{ -\int_0^1 \log y dy\right\}.$$

Why is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \log y\,\mathrm d y$ is a convergent improper integral, as 
$$\int \log y\,\mathrm d y=y\log y -y\quad\text{and}\quad y\log y -y\,\biggr|_0^1= (0\cdot\log 1-1)-0=-1,$$
so $\quad\displaystyle\exp\Bigl(\int_0^1 \log y\,\mathrm d y\Bigr)=\exp(-1)$.

Comment: There's nothing conditional about the convergence of that integral.

Comment: The integrand is not defined at $0$ (in the context of Riemann integral).

Comment: It's an improper integral, but the convergence is absolute, as the function doesn't change sign in the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible?  It's just another integral.